# Get the gradient at a specific point

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I'm looking to compute the gradient of a non analytic function at a very specific point, meaning that I'll need to interpolate ([scipy.interpolate.interp2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html)) the approximation of the gradient. I started with this minimal working example, and got lost at this point.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-200,200), np.linspace(-200,200))
z = -x**2 - y**2

v, u = np.gradient(z, 2, 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.quiver(x, y, u, v)

plt.show()
```

Moreover, I know that the gradient at point `(x[i], y[j])` is `u[i,j]*\hat x + v[i,j]*\hat y`. But things are going pretty difficult when the gradient isn't defined at some point.

Comment: There is some unclear language with 'vector' and 'gradient'. The gradient of a scalar function z=f(x,y) is a vector. Since your function is given as an analytic expression, you can compute the gradient for any point whatsoever with arbitrary precision (-2x,-2y). Using numpy.gradient will only be an approximation of the gradient based on the graininess of your grid.

Comment: roadrunner66: I've clarified the misuse of the word 'vector' in both the title and content. I was implicitly looking for the gradient of a non analytic function. If it wasn't the case, as you said, there wouldn't be such need.

Comment: Your call to `np.gradient` is also incorrect. `np.linspace` generates 50 output points by default, so the correct grid spacing is (400/49) = 8.163 in both the x and y directions

Comment: Just to further clarify, you use meshgrid and the definition of z just to make a working example, you don't have an actual function z=f(x,y), but gridded measurement data? And you want to compute the gradient at a point not on your data grid. Are you measurement data equally spaced (easier, use `rectbivariatespline` )?  Otherwise you can just use the method you mentioned to make a finer grid and get the gradient at those grid points. `interp2d' uses splines, so if your data are oversampled (fulfill the sampling theorem), there should be no problem.